# Discriminate Market apk and debug apk

Tags: android, apk

There is 2 APIs, one for `QA`(testing and debugging ) and other for `Production`
I need to run the `QA` api for debugging (that we created using eclipse) and `Production` api when we create market apk without changing the code. Is there any way to check using code whether it is debug apk or market apk currently running. Or anything that i can set in manifest
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where Ant can help you. I always use Eclipse to build the debug version, then use Ant for the release version, mainly because I need a different Google Maps API key for each. I have two versions of the main.xml, namely debugmain.xml and releasemain.xml. I've modified the release target in the build.xml, and added two extra targets :

```
<target name="check-release_main">
    <available file="${layout.dir}/releasemain.xml" property="releasemain.present" />
</target>


<target name="-copy-rel-main" depends="check-release_main" if="releasemain.present">
    <echo message="Hit copy rel main" />
    <copy file="${layout.dir}/releasemain.xml" tofile="${layout.dir}/main.xml" overwrite="true"/>
</target>
```

I changed the dependencies of the release target to depend on copy-rel-main:

```
<target name="release" depends="clean, -copy-rel-main.......
```

and the at the very end of the release target copied the debug version of main.xml to overwrite main.xml back to the debug version

```
    ......
    <echo message="Copying the debugmain.xml back to main.xml" />
    <echo message="ALWAYS LEFT IN DEBUG FROR ECLIPSE" />
    <copy file="${layout.dir}/debugmain.xml" tofile="${layout.dir}/main.xml" overwrite="true" />

</target>
```

You could adapt your versions to have some identifying text or colour in one of your elements to signify which version is running on your device

Answer (score 1):

When you sign the app, you can sign it in debug mode.  When you are ready to release, you can change the signature.  Here is more from the google documentation [Signing Your Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. The OP wants to expose a different API in debug mode vs. in production mode. The phone will treat both versions the same, except that it won't auto-update from a really-signed version to a signed-for-debug-mode version.

Comment: I Know this ninjasense and MatrixFrog you understood my problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a boolean in your XML files along with your strings:

```
<resources>
  <bool name="debug">true</bool>
</resources>
```

and then access it in your code using `this.getResources().getBoolean(R.debug)` (where `this` is an Activity or other Context). Keep it `true` most of the time and then set it to `false` for the release.

Comment: Thanks MatrixFrog. This is way i tried now. But is there any setting file or other that will change its value automatically for release version.

Comment: I suppose you could write a build script that switches it programmatically, but other than that, not that I know of. You could make it so that when it's in debug mode the words DEBUG MODE appear all over the place, making it unlikely you would release the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can also programatically check the signature of your app. I use the technique to log version information

```
final byte[] officalkey = {-58, -42, -44, -106, 90, -88, -87, -88, -52, -124, 84, 117, 66, 79, -112, -111, -46, 86, -37, 109};
final byte[] officaldebugkey = {-99, -69, 45, 71, 114, -116, 82, 66, -99, -122, 50, -70, -56, -111, 98, -35, -65, 105, 82, 43};

Signature raw = c.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(c.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures[0];
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(raw.toByteArray()));
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] der = cert.getEncoded();
md.update(der);
byte[] digest = md.digest();


if (Arrays.equals(digest, officalkey))
    apksign = c.getString(R.string.official_build);
else if (Arrays.equals(digest, officaldebugkey))
    apksign = c.getString(R.string.debug_build);
else
    apksign = c.getString(R.string.built_by,cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
```